# How to use merge function with collections as a map value in Java

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to understand better how to work with collections and functions **without streams** and I have the next code where I am trying to add a new value to an existing key in a Map where value is a Collection.

But I am stuck with what exactly parameters I need to pass to the merge function in addNewPhoneNumbers() method. So I need some help with this particular code piece and maybe some explanation **how it should work with merge or compute functions.**

```
import java.util.*;

class PhoneBook {
    private final Map<String, Collection<PhoneNumber>> nameToPhoneNumbersMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addNewPhoneNumbers(String name, Collection<PhoneNumber> numbers) {
        if (!nameToPhoneNumbersMap.containsKey(name)) {
            nameToPhoneNumbersMap.put(name, numbers);
        } else{
            System.out.println("name is already in the map, adding new phone...");
            nameToPhoneNumbersMap.merge(name, ??? , ???);
        }
    }

    public void printPhoneBook() {
        nameToPhoneNumbersMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println(k);
            v.forEach(vv -> System.out.println(vv.getType() + ": " + vv.getNumber()));
        });
        System.out.println("------");
    }
}

enum PhoneNumberType {
    MOBILE, HOME, WORK,
}

class PhoneNumber {

    private PhoneNumberType type;
    private String number;

    public PhoneNumber(PhoneNumberType type, String number) {
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public PhoneNumberType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook();

        List<PhoneNumber> saraPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PhoneNumber> johnPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        saraPhoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber(PhoneNumberType.HOME, "1234567"));
        johnPhoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber(PhoneNumberType.WORK, "8910"));

        phoneBook.addNewPhoneNumbers("Sara", saraPhoneNumbers);
        phoneBook.printPhoneBook();

        phoneBook.addNewPhoneNumbers("John", johnPhoneNumbers);
        phoneBook.printPhoneBook();

        //add a new name with a new phone number
        phoneBook.addNewPhoneNumbers("Tom", List.of(new PhoneNumber(PhoneNumberType.WORK, "11121314")));
        phoneBook.printPhoneBook();

        //add a new phone with a new phone type for an existing name
        phoneBook.addNewPhoneNumbers("Sara", List.of(new PhoneNumber(PhoneNumberType.MOBILE, "15161718")));
        phoneBook.printPhoneBook();
    }

}
```

For now the last *sout* result doesn't contain Sara's mobile phone number, but it should be like this:

> name is already in the map, adding new phone...
>
> Tom
>
> WORK: 11121314
>
> John
>
> WORK: 8910
>
> Sara
>
> HOME: 1234567
>
> **MOBILE: 15161718**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use computeIfAbsent to add a new collection if key is absent or add values if it exists

```
public void addNewPhoneNumbers(String name, Collection<PhoneNumber> numbers) {
    if (nameToPhoneNumbersMap.containsKey(name)) {
        System.out.println(name + " is already in the map, adding new phone...");
    }

    nameToPhoneNumbersMap.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(numbers);
}
```

You can achieve the same with merge, but need to take care of the fact that Collection.addAll returns a boolean. That is : in case the key already exists you need to add the new numbers to the old list and return the old list or the other way round.

```
public void addNewPhoneNumbers(String name, Collection<PhoneNumber> numbers) {
    if (nameToPhoneNumbersMap.containsKey(name)) {
        System.out.println(name + " is already in the map, adding new phone...");
    }
    nameToPhoneNumbersMap.merge(name, numbers, (oldValue,newValue) -> {
        oldValue.addAll(newValue);
        return oldValue;
    });
}
```

Comment: When you use `merge`,  `oldValue` will be whatever collection has been specified on the first `merge` call with this key. In the OP’s example, it happens to be an `ArrayList` but the OP also uses `List.of()` for the second call, so just changing the order of the calls would already break it.

Answer (score 0):

With merge you don't have to distinguish wether the name already exists or not:

```
public void addNewPhoneNumbers(String name, Collection<PhoneNumber> numbers) {
    if (nameToPhoneNumbersMap.containsKey(name)) {
        System.out.println("name is already in the map, adding new phone...");
    }
    nameToPhoneNumbersMap.merge(name, numbers ,
        (oldValue , newValue) -> { oldValue.addAll(newValue); return oldValue; }); 
}
```

Parameter 2 is what to add if name is a new value and parameter 3 the function how to merge the old with the new entry.
You may want to override equals and hashCode of PhoneNumber, so you could write

```
        (oldValue , newValue) -> { oldValue.addAll(newValue); return new HashSet(oldValue); });
```

generating no duplicates.

Comment: It makes more sense to use `oldValue = new HashSet(oldValue); oldValue.addAll(newValue); return oldValue;`, to only modify the new set.

Comment: @Holger You're right, I was just lazy